# Find out which MSI created registry key

Tags: windows, windows-registry, windows-installer

How can I find out which MSI created given registry key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The registry does not store information about it's creator. Thus, unless entry is associated with some of MSI's GUIDs there is not way to backtrack it.

All (well, most) MSI installation data is cached in `Windows\Installer` folder under random names, this is the place there all information required by uninstall stored. If your registry key name value is pretty unique, you can do a raw Unicode (UTF-16LE) string search in MSI files located in that folder, resulting in a MSI. You can further use [Orca tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to read information in that MSI.

Comment: Is there a database of all activities carried out by installed MSIs? Windows allows to uninstall apps so it must somehow know what exactly needs to be done during uninstallation.

Comment: See updated answer.